# how to switch another tab when click table row

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

There is two tab in my java swing interface. One tab has customer details table. I want to switch to the next other tab when I click a row of the table. Please help me. I tried this code.

```
        private void jTable2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
            int i = jtp.getSelectedIndex();
        jtp.setSelectedIndex(i == jtp.getTabCount() - 1 ? 0 : i + 1);

}
```

And I'm having exception.

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Tab count: 0
```

Comment: Print the `TabCount` of `jtb`. and also print the value of `i`

Comment: why didn't you read the tutorial as I suggested last time? Also, my advice was to _listen_ to the change of selection ... (mouse events will change the selection anyway, no reason to interfere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I want to switch to the next other tab when I click a row of the table."

What you want to do is add a `ListSelectionListener` to the table's selection model. When a row is selected, it will fire a `ListSelectionEvent`. You can just change the tab to whatever index you want it changed to from there.

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
     @Override
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
          if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
               tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabs.indexOfTab("Other Panel"));
          }
     }
});
```

See [**How to Use Tables**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [**How to Write ListSelectionListeners**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to learn more.

Full example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class TableSelection {

    public TableSelection() {
        JTabbedPane tabPane = createTabPane();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setContentPane(tabPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private JTabbedPane createTabPane() {
        JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
        JTable table = createTable(pane);
        pane.add(new JScrollPane(table), "Table Tab");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        pane.add(panel1, "Other Panel");
        return pane;
    }

    private JTable createTable(final JTabbedPane tabs) {
        String[][] data = {{"HELLO", "WORLD"}, {"HELLO", "WORLD"}};
        String[] cols = {"Hello", "World"};
        JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabs.indexOfTab("Other Panel"));
                }
            }
        });

        return table;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableSelection();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably want to take some action when the selection is _not_ adjusting :-) @Dilini: add a `!` to the if statement to ignore intermediate selection changes